How come this code is not presenting any errors, but also fails to print the desired code or display the graph
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics

airline_data = pd.read_csv('airlines-corgis.csv')

airline_data['CarrierNames'] = airline_data['CarrierNames'].str.split(',')
airline_data['TotalCarriers'] = airline_data['CarrierNames'].apply(len)
airline_data = airline_data.explode('CarrierNames')

airline_data['Time'] = pd.to_numeric(airline_data['Time'], errors='coerce')
airline_data_encoded = pd.get_dummies(airline_data, columns=          ['CarrierNames','Code','Name','MonthName'])

X = airline_data_encoded.drop(['Delays-Carrier', 'Delays-LateAircraft', 'Delays-   NAS', 'Delays-Security', 'Delays-Weather'], axis=1)
y = airline_data_encoded['Delayed']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,   random_state=16)

my_forest = RandomForestClassifier()

my_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = my_forest.predict(X_test)

cnf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, normalize='true')

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(cnf_matrix, annot=True, fmt='.2f',
        xticklabels=my_forest.classes_,
        yticklabels=my_forest.classes_)
plt.title('Normalized Confusion Matrix')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Value')
plt.ylabel('True Value')
plt.show()

print('Length of X_train:', len(X_train))
print('Feature Importances:', my_forest.feature_importances_)

I have been trying to create a random forest classifier, heat map, and determine the most important features impacting delays (which delay type), but when I run the code, nothing appears.

If you just run plt.scatter(0, 0) you should see a figure with a dot in the centre - I presume nothing shows up when you run this? If so, consider simplifying your code to just a simple plotting command to encourage more answers. Which editor are you plotting in?

Yes, nothing appeared. I am using idle.

I am not too familiar with IDLE and can't find much information on this sort of problem. Might be worth considering a more widely-used IDE. Some are tailored for data science work which seems to be the sort of thing you're doing.
